# fullcalendar.js is not reading the php json feed

Tags: javascript, php, json

i want to pre-poulate my fullcalendar instance via a php json feed.

The page is loading fine (no 404 or sth like that) but the calendar is not showing any of the events.

generating the json:

```
<?php
require("../config/config.php");
$uid = $_SESSION['uid'];
$res = $db->query("SELECT * FROM slots WHERE tid = '$uid'");
$data = array();
while($row = $res->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $event = array();
        $event['editable'] = false;
        $event['id'] = "fixE_".$row['id'];
        $event['title'] = getSlotStatus($row['status']);
        $event['sid'] = $row['sid'];
        $event['status'] = $row['status'];
        $event['start'] = $row['start'];
        $event['end'] = $row['end'];
        $event['standby'] = $row['standby'];
        if(strpos($data['status'],"_old"))
            {
                $event['textColor'] = '#000000';
                $event['color'] = '#cccccc';
                $event['className'] = 'lessonSlotOld';
            }
        else
            {
                $event['color'] = getColorCode($row['status']);
                if($row['standby'])
                    {
                        $event['borderColor'] = '#0000FF';
                    }
            }
        $data[] = $event;
    }
echo json_encode(array("events"=>$data));?>
```

and here's the part of the fullcalendar code where i am inserting the feed:

```
events:
        {
            url: 'include/fetchSlots.php',
            type: 'POST',
            error: function(){alert("There was an error fetching events")}
        },
```

the json output of the php looks like the following (this is just a part because the whole response would be too much ;) )

```
{"events":[{"editable":false,"id":"fixE_164","title":"Slot is closed","sid":"0","status":"closed","start":"2015-06-06T04:00:00+08:00","end":"2015-06-06T04:30:00+08:00","standby":"0","color":"#B20000"}]}
```

Comment: using dev tools in browser (F12), can you see the json being requested and returned?  If so, post your js code.  If not, probably also post your js code, haha.  If the json page loads fine on it's own it's probably a js error, you can see those errors under the cosole section of your dev tools.

Comment: thanks for the advise, I'm using FF the page is processed and the json is returned. What looks a little weird to me is, that the json is returned as the following: events:Array,0:Object,1:Object,2:Object and so on. in the objects i can find the correct data that was returned in json. I'm not really familiar with json, should it be "object"? EDIT: if i add the events via mysql->php-> echo inline into the javascript, it's all working fine. but i wanted to use the refetchEvents method of fullcalendar and that's not bringing me new values from the db...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so here's the solution/the mistake.

The only problem that fullcalendar has is the line where the actual json is posted:

```
echo json_encode(array("events"=>$data));
```

fullcalendar doesnt want the "events" and it doesnt want the twice wrapped array. so the solution to this is simply to output the data-array directly:

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

then, the events are all loaded correctly.

ah and for all watchmen out there, yes i found the mistake with the wrong named variable ;)

```
if(strpos($data['status'],"_old"))
```

to

```
if(strpos($row['status'],"_old"))
```